# How to have a $resource return sample data in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Assume I have a angular service with the resource:

```
var res = $resource('/myurl/:index', {index: '@index'})
```

Is there a way for me to make it such that I can define arbirary paths such that when within my service I call:

$res.query()

I can get some hardcoded output of "[1,2,3]" without having the resource actually calling the server or expecting the server to have a function that supports the query()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're approaching this a bit wrong.  `$resource` is a **factory** for creating Services where you specify the url and other parameters for a given API endpoint.  If you have a fake or test API endpoint, just create a fake Service that returns the hard coded data.

Here's an example:

```
.factory('TestDataResource', function() {

    return {
        query: function() {

            // Return Hard-coded data
            return [1, 2, 3];
        }
    }
});
```

And then you can use it in your controllers or wherever, for example:

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, TestDataResource) {

    $scope.data = TestDataResource.query();
    // $scope.data should contain [1, 2, 3]
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you want to be able to use $promise.then of the resource object !

Answer (score 1):

You may use a JSON file for the sample-data.

Answer (score 0):

`$resource` calls `$http` under the covers so you should be able to use `$httpBackend` to mock responses. [This page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) has a wealth on information on this.